# Filesystem.writeFile() crashes when trying to write large PDF files on my Capacitor Ionic applications

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I have apps made using the Ionic Framework which uses capacitor (Angular). The apps are deployed on both Android and IOS. From within the apps you can download a generated PDF.

I use the following code to do so:

```
  static async writeAndOpenFile(data: Blob, fileName: string) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(data);
    reader.onloadend = async function () {
      const base64data = reader.result;

      try {
        const result = await Filesystem.writeFile({
          path: fileName,
          data: <string>base64data,
          directory: Directory.Data,
          recursive: true
        });

        let fileOpener: FileOpener = new FileOpener();
        fileOpener.open(result.uri, data.type)
          .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
          .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
      } catch (e) {
        console.error('Unable to write file', e);
      }
    }
  }
```

however when I try to write larger PDF files the applications crash. I am wondering if theres and solution for this

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `Filesystem.writeFile(...)` method is not intended to write large files. You should use one of the following two plugins instead:

- [capacitor-blob-writer](https://github.com/diachedelic/capacitor-blob-writer)
- [capacitor-file-chunk](https://github.com/qrclip/capacitor-file-chunk)

To avoid such problems, you should not load the file into the WebView at all.

Comment: Thanks, I will give those a go. What is an alternative to loading into WebView. As PDF's are generated in the app client side and can be done offline. 

Cheers

Comment: In this case they should be directly generated on the native side using a Capacitor plugin.